Find inertia remaining in a power system post trip
Im trying to figure out this exam question:

A Generator Trip event occurred at 01:17:00 am on the Irish all-island
electric power system. The frequency measured is shown in figure Q3(d)
with associated frequency values tabulated in table Q3(d) below.
Define the following concepts as outlined in Grid code and obtain
their values associated with the frequency event shown.
If, at the time of the trip, the all-island power system was operating
at minimum level of inertia required by current operational
constraints and the 408 kVA generating unit was generating 350 MW
prior to tripping. Calculate the inertia remaining on the transmission
system post trip. Generating unit machine inertia constant H = 5.5
Ws/VA.


The minimum level of inertia is 23,000 MWs.
Firstly, I think 408 kVA is a typo and it should be 408 MVA.
So I calculated the stored energy:
408 MVA * 5.5 s = 2244 MWs (stored energy in machine)
The trip was at 01:17:00 and over at 01:17:20 (the lowest frequency) so 20 seconds.
Therefore the stored energy used over 20 seconds is 2244 MWs * 20 = 44,880 MWs. But this is more than the minimum level of inertia of 23,000, so I guess I have done something wrong...

This sounds like a homework/test question, for which we require you to show the work you have done already.

I’m voting to close this question because it appears to be an academic problem without an attempted solution.
